# Text not centering on message% in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I have following simple GUI code:

```
#lang racket/gui
(define myfr   (new frame% [label ""] [width 200] [height 100]))
(define mymsg (new message% [label "See text position here."][parent myfr]))
(define mytf (new text-field% [label "Enter some text here."][parent myfr]))
(define bt  (new button% [parent myfr] [label "Reset text"]
           [callback (lambda (b e)   
                         (send mymsg set-label 
                              (send mytf get-value)))]))
(send myfr show #t)
```

Initially, the text position on message% is well centralized. However, when I change the text, it is no more well-centered. Why is this happening and how can this be corrected so that the new text is also well centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[auto-resize #t]` to your message:

```
(define mymsg (new message%    [label "See text position here."] [parent myfr] [auto-resize #t]))
```

Comment: Yes, it works. What is the option to adjust alignment of text on message% ?

Comment: I don't think there any?  You can put the message% inside some kind of panel and let the panel align its children.